# Rxjs subscribe called twice ionic 3 angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, ionic3

I am facing a problem with **Rxjs subscribe**, it's been called twice, I already search in the google and StackOverflow, there is some question already asked but none of the questions is helpful for my case, I also didn't find whats wrong with my code.

**Here is my code:**
**login.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {
  AlertController,
  IonicPage,
  LoadingController,
  MenuController,
  NavController,
  NavParams,
  ToastController
} from 'ionic-angular';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import {AuthServiceProvider} from "../../providers/auth-service/auth-service";
import {DashboardPage} from "../dashboard/dashboard";
import {SignupPage} from "../signup/signup";
import {FormControl, FormGroup, Validators} from "@angular/forms";
import {Network} from "@ionic-native/network";


@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html',
})
export class LoginPage{

  loginForm: FormGroup;
  user:any = new Object();
  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    public navParams: NavParams,
    private authService:AuthServiceProvider,
    private alertCtrl: AlertController,
    public storage: Storage,
    public menuCtrl: MenuController,
    private loading: LoadingController,
    private network: Network,
    private toast: ToastController
  ) {
    this.menuCtrl.enable(false,'menu');
    this.loginForm= new FormGroup({
      mobile: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
      password: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
    });

  }


  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log("called")
  }

  login() {
    if(this.network.type === 'none' || this.network.type === 'unknown'){
      this.toast.create({
        message:`You are offline, please connect your wifi or 3g`,
        position:'top',
        duration:3000
      }).present();
    } else {
      let spinner = this.loading.create({
        content: 'Please wait...'
      });
      spinner.present();
      this.authService.userLogin(this.user)
        .subscribe(
          response => {
            console.log(response);
            if (response.status === "ok") {
              console.log(response.status);
              this.authService.isLoggedIn(response);
              this.navCtrl.setRoot(DashboardPage);
            } else {
              console.log(response.status);
              let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
                title: response.status,
                subTitle: response.msg,
                buttons: ['Dismiss']
              });
              alert.present()
            }
            spinner.dismiss();
          })
    }
  }
}
```

when the authentication is failed, it shows failure alert twice and also when authentication succeeds then it also shows failure alert and then immediately succeed and go dashboard page.

**Here is my auth-service.ts**

```
userLogin(user):Observable<any>{
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type':  'application/json'
      })
    };
    let ttl = 60*60*24*30;
    let delay = 'all';
    const url = ApiEndPoint+'customer_login';
    let req = this.http
      .post(url, user,httpOptions)
      .map(data=> {
        return data;
      })
      .catch((error:any)=>{
        return Observable.throw({Error:error});
      });
    return this.cache.loadFromDelayedObservable(url, req,'user',ttl,delay);
  }
```

Right direction would be highly appreciated.
**Thanks**

Comment: share the loadFromDelayedObservable please

Comment: **loadFromDelayedObservable ** is built in function in ionic-cache service
[here is document](https://github.com/Nodonisko/ionic-cache)

Comment: what is `alert.present()` method for? is it for showing error

Comment: apart from that I do have a question is not your spinner dismissed before your request is resolved?

Comment: yes, `alert.present() ` is showing the error message, the spinner is dismissed when the request is resolved, I `dismissed` the spinner in `if and else` checking, but now I put it after if condition, it works same. thanks

Comment: try with delayType = 'none';

Comment: `If delay type = 'none' ` then it will never call the API before the cache is expired. @AlanGrosz

Comment: I checked it now, it still works same. and I `console ` the `subscription resolve`  it still shows twice.